# Panel not shows after key pressed

Tags: vb.net, button, panel

I faced a strange problem, I set a "hotkey" to show and hide help panel and it is working until I press a close (hide) button on that panel, after that the "hotkey" does not work any more. Also I have a button on my Form that shows and hide this panel as well, and it works all the time, it is only a problem with the "hotkey".

This is what I have done for the "hotkey".

```
Private Sub Me_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.H Then
        If Panel1.Visible = True Then
            Panel1.Visible = False
        ElseIf Panel1.Visible = False Then
            Panel1.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But if I only use this hotkey, I can set visible = true/false as many Times I want, it only stop working after I press any buton on the panel.

In Design View: in panel1
- Panel1.Visible = False

- lblMenu
- btnClose
- btnReset
- btnSettings
- btnExitToMenu
- btnExitApp

Some More Code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub debug_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblMenu.Text = "Menu"
    Panel1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Me_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.H Then
        If Panel1.Visible = True Then
            Panel1.Visible = False
        ElseIf Panel1.Visible = False Then
            Panel1.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnResume_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnResume.Click
    If Panel1.Visible = True Then
        Panel1.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnRestart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRestart.Click
    'For restar configuration
End Sub

Private Sub btnSettings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSettings.Click
    'Display additional settings
End Sub

Private Sub btnExitToMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExitToMenu.Click
    Dim msg = "Are you sure you want exit to menu?"
    Dim response = MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnExitGame_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExitGame.Click
    Dim msg = "Are you sure you want to close this app?"
    Dim response = MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Form1.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMenu.Click
    If Panel1.Visible = True Then
        Panel1.Visible = False
    ElseIf Panel1.Visible = False Then
        Panel1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

**That is full code i used**

Comment: I have several forms, but non of them are in use in this code. Also this form is the only one that is not included inside a window, so it's just like you do a new form.

Comment: Ok, now I sended you the full code

Comment: yes I change it sorry, i tried with different keys. I am going to change it for the H again I'm sorry one again

Comment: yes, and all the buttons except "btnMenu" are inside the panel which is hidden.

Comment: 1. You want me to change Panel1.Visible = False to True at formLoad?
2. it does no matter which buton on the panel I press, after that the hotkey goes to somwhere else. 3. What do you mean by breake point?

Comment: Me.Focus() sort this problem in some way, but still I have to add it to everything what is inside a panel, because if someone accidentaly click somwhere else... then it will stop working again, adding Me.Focus() to timer :P not working as it supose to work... any ideas?

Comment: search RegisterHotKey: I think it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is how I make it work

```
        Public Declare Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer, ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
        Public Declare Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
        Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312
        Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
            If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
                TextBox1.Text = m.LParam '<-- 2. After you run the form press the key you set in 1. and copy it
            End If
            If m.LParam = 4718592 Then  '<-- 3. paste this here to use wanted key
                    If Panel1.Visible = True Then
                        Panel1.Visible = False
                    ElseIf Panel1.Visible = False Then
                        Panel1.Visible = True
                    End If
            End If
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End Sub
        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Call RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 9, 0, Keys.H) '<-- 1. Add a key what you want to use
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
            UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle.ToInt32, 0)
        End Sub
```

Thanks to tezzo

Answer (score 0):

If adding an handler for all the other buttons solves it for you then put this in your code:

Add a handler for all your button when the form loads like this:

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each cntl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf cntl Is Button Then
                AddHandler DirectCast(cntl, Button).Click, AddressOf HandleMyButtonClicksPlease
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

 Private Sub HandleMyButtonClicksPlease(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
       If Panel1.Visible = True Then
            Panel1.Visible = False
        ElseIf Panel1.Visible = False Then
            Panel1.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: The button on Form is working fine, the problem is with the e.KeyCode after pressing a button on the panel

Comment: What happens in debug?

Comment: Error List gives me no errors, warnings or messages, I also put it in Try Catch, but as I said, this not throw any error it's just nothing happen after press a key

Comment: Yes I did, with no Luck... But i found something strange again... after I use te close buton on panel i cannot use the hotkey, BUT if I minimalize my form and restore it I can use the hotkey again, but after I use a buton on the panel hotkey once again stop working... I think to record this and show you this thing from youtube

Comment: Read this http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets10p3.html try switching Me with the object ID.

Comment: I just don't believe it, I add to that handler a btnClose.KeyDown... and it's working, but I don't understand why it's happend, because I also tryed to click on the form and press the hotkey, and it was not working...

Comment: It is working when I add ..., btnClose.KeyDown only for that button in panel, but... ehh... if I press any other buttons, again same problem appears, I have 7 buttons in there for now, it seems to be pointless of adding each button to the Handler

Comment: is there an option to add Me.Focus() to all panel buttons?
Because this thing solve it, but still I have to add it to each button to make it work.

Comment: You can use something like this:
   MyPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()

Comment: Just before you posted I figured to do something like this
Sub Panel_Close() Handles Panel1.VisibleChanged
        Me.Focus()
    End Sub

I am now checking this what you posted

Comment: I do not think I know how to use that (I mean for this situation)

Comment: This is all I have for now in the panel1 + (Me.KeyDown), The rest of this code are calculations that depends on user choices in options

Comment: Also , put debug in all of your events handlers. I think there might be an event that gets called an return visible to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I just don't believe it is that simple, earlier I found out that is a Focus problem. So the code can be something like this:

```
    Private Sub Me_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LostFocus
        Me.Focus()
    End Sub
```